# Azure Log Insights - How to aggregate events per hour

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics

I am trying to monitor Azure ASR VM Disk churn & throughput processing.

I can get the last hours worth of VM Churn & Upload rate with the following query:

```
Perf
| where ObjectName == "ASRAnalytics"
| where InstanceName contains "VMName"
| where TimeGenerated >= ago(1h) 
| project TimeGenerated, CounterName, Churn_MBps = todouble(CounterValue)/5242880
| render timechart
```

This will only get me either a line chart showing what the VM upload activity looked like, or a table of values with columns TimeGenerated, Countername, Churn_MBps

How can I aggregate these values into a single value per counter name (SourceVmThrpRate,SourceVmCurnRate) that will show me the total aggregate Churn or Thrp for the total hour?

Comment: Can you please attach an screenshot of the source data?

Answer (score 3):

[Kusto Query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/) has aggregated functions; like `count()`, `avg()`, `max()`, etc - you can read more about [Aggregated Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/avg-aggfunction).

I hope below updated query helps; I have added `summarize` but I have not validated result as I will have different data.

`| summarize avg(Churn_MBps) by bin(TimeGenerated, 1h), CounterName`

```
Perf
| where ObjectName == "ASRAnalytics"
| where InstanceName contains "VMName"
| where TimeGenerated >= ago(1h) 
| project TimeGenerated, CounterName, Churn_MBps = todouble(CounterValue) / 5242880
| summarize avg(Churn_MBps) by bin(TimeGenerated, 1h), CounterName
| render timechart
```